# Some random questions about Plugin Dev for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, rider

I am new to IntelliJ Plugin Development and would like to write a little Plugin for a C# Framework I am using. The Plugin would be for the Rider IDE. The things I would like to know are:

- How do I execute Code after a project was opened in the IDE?
- How do I run a command in the background and display the output of that program in a window that is docked in the bottom like the Terminal Window. Alternativley: how do I open a new terminal and run a command in it?
- How do I run Code when a file is saved and how do I check if the class that lives inside this files Implements a certain interface?
- How do I add settings to my plugin?
- How do I add a new Option to the "Mark Directory As" submenu and how do I acces all directories marked as a certain type?
- How do I find out on which OS we are currently running?

If anybody could point me in the right way on any of these questions, it would mean the world to me :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you need to ask this in the intellij plugin dev forum? Too many things about intellij internal.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html

Comment: Try to study this Rider plugin https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity

Answer (score 1):

Some more plugins to study:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity
- https://github.com/maartenba/rider-plugin-globaljson
- https://github.com/maartenba/rider-plugin-xdt
- https://github.com/maartenba/rider-plugin-reversepackagesearch
- https://github.com/maartenba/rider-plugin-svcutil

All are pretty basic (apart from the Unity one which is larger in scope) and should help you get started. Note these target Rider 2017.2 currently, best edit the Gradle file to point to your own Rider installation folder to target the latest versions.

Other than that, look at http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html and the general plugin development forums at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development. Another good way to start building plugins is look at the various open-source plugins at https://plugins.jetbrains.com (there are quite a few that do really nice things and provide a pointer to where to start on the above).